# How can I create my custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml

I'm new in Android & I want to create a custom actionbar for my application like the image below:
[image]

How can I create this? In the circle, I want to insert my image and instead of "welcome", I want to write my user's name.
What can I do for this?
Appreciating any help.

**Edit:**

My layout's theme is AppTheme, and it has an action bar I don't want that,How can I delete it to Insert custom actionbar?

Comment: The short answer is you should use a Toolbar. Have a look at this example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/ .

Comment: This is a default template activity in Android Studio

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani (The text is from the site you inserted)" it is available for use from this API (21 API ) level and above." my min API is 8,so can I use toolbar?

Comment: I do not think you can use Toolbar on API 8. As for the support library, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar is available for old OSs, but it is available only on API 9 and up. If I were you, I'd consider raising the API level to API 15 as only 0.1% of the users are still on API 8 and a bit more are on lower APIs (see Android Dashboards). This way, you'll have access to the more modern APIs.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani yes,you are right.I will increase app's min API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around my problem,I found my response:
I create an xml file with linearlayout and whithin its tags I added the code I inserted below.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        >


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:src="@drawable/books2"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toolbar"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />


</FrameLayout>
```

For Imageview's shape,I use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/blue"
    android:centerColor="@color/blue"
    android:endColor="@color/blue"
    android:type="linear"/>

<corners
    android:radius="70dp"
    />
<size
    android:height="40dp"
    android:width="40dp"
    />
```

and I include this in my activity's layout XML file.

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

For this part of my question:
**Edit:
My layout's theme is AppTheme, and it has an action bar I don't want that,How can I delete it to Insert custom actionbar?**

I add this code to style.xml file :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml file within  tag,I added this :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Hope it will useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

At Manifest file add the following in activity tag

```
android:label="Welcome"
```

You gonna need to add a Toolbar and a Floating Action Button to your activty xml file
Add the toolbar as child of AppBar like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            .....>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                ...../>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

For the Floating Action Button add the following inside the activity xml file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/name_of_image</item>/>
```